# Ruby Subtract one number from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a ruby function for subtracting from all elements in an array?

```
[2,4,7,8,9] - 8 = [-6,-4,-1,0,1]
```

This does not work but I would rather not do this with more complex cases.

```
[2,4,7,8,9] - [8,8,8,8,8] = [-6,-4,-1,0,1]
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You want `map`, which lets you apply a transformation to each element of an Enumerable, returning the resulting array:

```
[2,4,7,8,9].map { |i| i - 8 } # => [-6, -4, -1, 0, 1]
```

---

As an aside, your second example most definitely does *not* work this way:

```
[2,4,7,8,9] - [8,8,8,8,8] = [-6,-4,-1,0,1]
```

Subtraction removes the items in the second array from the first array, yielding `[2,4,7,9]`, *not* your expected `[-6,-4,-1,0,1]`.

Answer (score 3):

Worth mentioning the `narray` gem as an alternative to using Ruby's built-in `Array` and `.map`. If your numeric arrays are much larger than your example, then `narray` is optimised to do maths on them, and also works as you initially suggested:

```
> require 'narray'
 => true

> a = NArray[10,9,8,2,3]
 => NArray.int(5):
[ 10, 9, 8, 2, 3 ]

> a - 8
 => NArray.int(5):
[ 2, 1, 0, -6, -5 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what map/collect are for (yes, they both do exactly the same, collect is there for historical reasons).

```
[1,2,3,4,5].map do |elem|
  elem - 1
end
```

or using collect and the alternative do/end syntax (also valid in map)

```
[1,2,3,4,5].collect { |elem| elem - 1 }
```

both return

```
 => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Your second example isn't using a "lambda" instead of a "block", both versions of your code are using procs. `{}` is just an alternate syntax for `do/end`, they're identical.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Array
  def to_proc
    proc { |receiver| receiver.send *self }
  end
end

[2,4,7,8,9].map &[:-, 8] #=> [-6,-4,-1,0,1]
```

Comment: Boris - Your opinion please :)

Comment: @Priti: My opinion is that you became better `Benchmark` user than I, but you got the labels switched :-))) Let me try it on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the map or collect method in following way.

```
[2,4,7,8,9].collect {|e| e-8}
=> [-6, -4, -1, 0, 1]

[2,4,7,8,9].map {|e| e-8}
=> [-6, -4, -1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JRuby then you could try MDArray that has similar functionalities as NArray.  Not to much documentation though.

Answer (score -2):

You can use external iterator for the second case. Try this:

```
ary = [8,8,8,8,8].each
[2,4,7,8,9].map{ |e| e - ary.next } # => [-6,-4,-1,0,1]
```

Comment: It's only useful when you need to subtract from each element of the array different number.